# Prove that the set of open spheres is countable.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me with the following problem:

I'm trying to prove that the following set of open spheres of $\mathbb R^2$ with $x_1,y_1,r ∈ \mathbb Q$ is countable:

$$S[(x_1,y_1),r]=\{(x,y∈\mathbb R^2: \sqrt {(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}<r\}$$

I know that  $\mathbb Q$ is countable so if I take $$f:S→\mathbb Q, f(S)=[(x_1,y_1),r]= \mathbb Q ×\mathbb Q ×\mathbb Q =\mathbb Q^3$$  is also countable, right? 
Is that enough?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure that $f$ is injective.

Comment: It looks like you're using /epsilon instead of /in for set membership symbol.

Comment: Its $Q^3$ not $Q^2$. It seems enough to me, if you have already proven product of countable is countable

Comment: It is $f : S \to \mathbb Q^3$ (not $\mathbb N$). This is injective and $\mathbb Q^3$ is countable which is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general strategy for showing that a certain set $S$ is countable is to find an *injective* function $f\colon S\to\mathbb Q$. Note, this is not true if the function is not injective, for instance consider the function $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb Q$ sending everything to $0$.

So it suffices to show that your function is injective. But this is clear, since if two open spheres have the same center and radius, then they are the same sphere.